# What does the "Changed Files" pane of the VCS "Log Tab" of WebStorm show for merged commit in Git

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

The documentation for the "Changed Files" pane of [log tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html#changedFiles) states that:

> The Changed Files pane is located on the right of the tool window and
>   shows the list of files that were modified within the selected commit.

I'm wondering however what it shows for the merge commit?

[image]

For example, I have the following history:

[image]

and when the  `merge branch 'l'` is selected the "changed files" pane is empty.

The diff for `merge branch 'l'` with `i2` shows one modified file `a.txt`, and the diff for `merge branch 'l'` with `l1` shows one modified file `a.txt` and one added file `c.txt`. So the `Change Files" pane doesn't show these differences.

I've done some experiments and it seems that the pane shows files that conflicted during the merge and were **not** resolved using content from either of the conflicting sides but rather were resolved with custom content different from any of the branch commits involved in the merge. Is it so?

Comment: I don't use webstorm, so I can only guess, but it seems likely that they are just running `git show` and letting it do all the work. `git show`, for a merge, produces a *combined diff*, which is described (not very well) in the `git diff` documentation, which includes the line: "Note that combined diff lists only files which were modified from all parents." What this means is that `merge:path` has a different hash ID from both `merge^1:path` and `merge^2:path` (or merge^n:path for all n parents, for an octopus merge).

Comment: This particular rule, by the way, is all from a short-cut code path inside the diff engine for merge commits: to avoid doing a lot of expensive computation, Git dives into the tree object attached to the merge, and to the (presumably different) trees of each of the parents. It looks up the specific hash ID of the path names. If the path exists in any parent with the same ID as it has in the child, that path gets dropped from the file candidates list. This same short-cut code is used in part to implement `--follow`.

Comment: @torek, thanks a lot for you comment! So what you're saying seems to be in line with my observations: _...the pane shows files that conflicted during the merge and were **not** resolved using content from either of the conflicting sides but rather were resolved with custom content different from any of the branch commits involved in the merge_, correct? I'm a bit confused because without a conflict and manual custom modification the hash of the `path` can still be different from both parents, right? Webstorm doesn't seem to show these kind of merged paths

Comment: also, can you please elaborate on the second comment, I didn't understand it

Comment: It's difficult to explain well, in part because it's tricky even to understand. The code itself is in [tree-diff.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/tree-diff.c). There is an explanatory comment [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1a4e40aa5dc16564af879142ba9dfbbb88d1e5ff/tree-diff.c#L313-L393) but unless you are familiar with diff algorithms it may be entirely unhelpful. The tree entries are sorted (raw ASCII sort) so the "min" is the next file alphabetically, as it were.

Comment: The handling functions (defined elsewhere - up around line 180) are what determine which paths survive to the final diff. The default for a combined diff is to check the hash IDs attached to each parent, vs the hash ID for the current tree (or lack of hash ID when files are not present). If rename or copy detection are enabled, it looks like unpaired files can perhaps be paired by the dispatch-receivers, but that's not at all clear to me.

Comment: @torek, thanks, I think it makes sense for me to create a separate question how `unified diff works`. What do you think?

Comment: "unified diff" is usually taken to mean "vs context or not-even-context diff". Git's *combined* diffs are peculiar to Git. So I'm not sure what you'd be asking. Also, any graphical interface *could* be doing its own special thing: a program can always run `git show -m` on a merge commit to split it into N separate diffs, one for each parent.

Comment: @torek, yeah, I was asking about `combined` diff. But probably I first need to figure what command IntelliJ runs. Appreciate your comments

Answer (score 2):

Until 2017.3, for the merge commits it showed the diff introduced inside this merge commit (just like `git show`).

In 2017.3 a new feature was added to show differences compared to each parent https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148143

Comment: thanks, so where can I read about this new feature in 2017.3? and specifically the algorithm (git commands) it uses to show the files? is it how it's shown in [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148143#comment=27-1824850) - combined, from both git diff  commands? `git show` command is not used?

Comment: There is no any documentation specifying this, but why do you need to know exact commands? `git show` is not used. Before the change, `git log -c` was used, now `git log -m` is used to find changes comparing to all parents. Conflicted files are calculated.

Comment: I wanted to know exact commands because then I could read git documentation and understand what algorithm is used to show files there. What you're saying is that now `git log -m` is used, can you please elaborate a bit on `Conflicted files are calculated`?